# Apply search on 'when' conditional in ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm running a playbook against a hosts file that looks like this

```
[windows_eu]
server1
server2

[windows_amer]
server3
server4

[linux_eu]
server5
server6

[linux_amer]
server7
server8
```

I have a block of tasks that I want to run only if the inventory_hostname is in one of the linux groups, ie

```
when: inventory_hostname in groups.linux*
```

But this syntax throws an error. Is there a way to do a look up on the groups to check for a string?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try if this works. I have not tested it.

```
when: inventory_hostname in ['group_names'| regex_search('(linux)')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, no joy with this one.

Answer (score 0):

Got this with

```
group_names | select('search','linux') | list | count > 0
```